# A service that delivers common vocabulary daily?

Tags: discussion, resources, online-resources

I have subscribed to Merriam Webster, dictionary.com, and a few other online dictionaries to send me words daily, but frankly, they send me vocabulary that I have never come across in my life and never seen in any book or article. Practicing these words is fun, but I've realized it's undermined my ability to talk in a simple fashion that everyone can understand. Is there a service that sends the most common advanced or intermediate vocabulary daily?

Comment: How about [A.Word.A.Day](https://wordsmith.org/words/plunderbund.html)?

Comment: Daily newspapers?

Comment: I doubt one can construct one; after the first few thousand words, what is common is going to depend heavily on whom you encounter in daily life and what you talk and write about. Looking at the MW list, there are many words I use on a regular basis — *acolyte* or *salubrious*, say — others I know but rarely have cause to use, e.g. *risorgimento* or *lagniappe* — and some which I have honestly never encountered before, like *festinate* or *wifty*. Words you learn from reading and conversation are going to fit more naturally into your writing and future conversation than anything from a list.

Comment: @choster your comment has without doubt exponentially increased the number of internet searches for "define wifty" ;-)